# Doxygen generation stops at 'Searching for documented variables...'

Tags: variables, search, doxygen, freeze

I currently want to create a doxygen documentation for a large C++ source code project (2400+ files).

The process stops at the following step:

```
Searching for enumerations...
Searching for documented typedefs...
Searching for members imported via using declarations...
Searching for included using directives...
Searching for documented variables...
```

I've waited more than 12 hours for this step, and there wasn't any progress at this point (Windows Task Manager says one core is working at 100 % (13 % overall) with 95 600 KB of memory usage).

My machine is an Intel Xeon E5-1620, 8 Cores @ 3.5 GHz with 8 GB of RAM.

This is the doxygen config file which I'm using.

```
# Doxyfile 1.8.10

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = "Phil's FSD Doc"
PROJECT_NUMBER         = 
PROJECT_BRIEF          = 
PROJECT_LOGO           = 
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = D:\kbPhil\doxygen\generatedDoc
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = English
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        = 
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    = 
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 3
ALIASES                = 
TCL_SUBST              = 
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = YES
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = NO
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      = 
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = NO
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = NO
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = NO
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = NO
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = 
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    = 
LAYOUT_FILE            = 
CITE_BIB_FILES         = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = ..
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.tcl \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf \
                         *.as \
                         *.js
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = 
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = 
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = 
EXAMPLE_PATH           = 
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             = 
INPUT_FILTER           = 
FILTER_PATTERNS        = 
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS = 
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = YES
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
CLANG_OPTIONS          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = html
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            = 
HTML_FOOTER            = 
HTML_STYLESHEET        = 
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  = 
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       = 
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = NO
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = NO
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               = 
HHC_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     = 
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               = 
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   = 
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  = 
QHG_LOCATION           = 
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = YES
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     = 
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       = 
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       = 
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     = 
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         = latex
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         = 
LATEX_HEADER           = 
LATEX_FOOTER           = 
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET = 
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      = 
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    = 
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    = 
RTF_SOURCE_CODE        = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             = 
MAN_LINKS              = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the DOCBOOK output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX = 
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           = 
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  = 
PREDEFINED             = __attribute__(x)=
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      = 
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               = 
GENERATE_TAGFILE       = 
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
PERL_PATH              = /usr/bin/perl
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
MSCGEN_PATH            = 
DIA_PATH               = 
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 8
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           = 
CLASS_GRAPH            = NO
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = NO
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = NO
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               = 
DOTFILE_DIRS           = 
MSCFILE_DIRS           = 
DIAFILE_DIRS           = 
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      = 
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  = 
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using, looks like 1.8.10. What happens with the newest version?

Comment: I'm currently working with version 1.8.11 (release date 30-12-2015) which should be the latest version (according to [doxygen changelog 2016-08-10](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/changelog.html)). Only my script is a little bit older.

Comment: Difficult problem. 2400 files will take a while but not that long. Looks like you are stuck in a recursive routine. Seen the memory usage it does not look like it is swapping, but can you try it on a Windows machine with more memory? Can you also try it on a Linux machine and see what happens? Any chance to get a stack trace (Linux with gdb?)? Other possibility is to try to reduce the number of files and see what the offending file / set of files is. I case it is not proprietary is there a place where I can find it?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.